# Creating multiple tables in firebase instance

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a firebase instance with a table of products. When adding a new product, I have a dropdown input that I want to pull a list of users from to select which one is entering a new product. I'm currently running this to get the list of users:

```
<select ng-model="user">
    <option value="{{product.user}}" ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.user}}</option>
</select>
```

From this JSON structure:

```
    {
    "products" : {
    "-K4xfUMY53523LSYZ0bhS" : {
      "category" : "Marketing",
      "comment" : "this is a comment",
      "notes" : "Note on the task",
      "due" : "Fri Dec 2 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
      "profile_pic" : "url-to-picture",
      "read" : true,
      "task" : "example task to be completed",
      "user" : "Elon"
    },
    "-K5cBQWgDVP_5uWUW-g6" : {
      "category" : "Sales",
      "comment" : "this is a comment",
      "notes" : "Note on the task",
      "due" : "Fri Dec 2 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
      "profile_pic" : "url-to-picture",
      "read" : true,
      "task" : "Fix this title",
      "user" : "Mike"
    },
    "-K5cdlpzdF5mBtPJQ5z6" : {
      "category" : "Planning",
      "comment" : "this is a comment",
      "due" : "Fri Dec 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
      "notes" : "Note on the task",
      "profile_pic" : "url-to-picture",
      "read" : false,
      "task" : "This is a task",
      "user" : "Mike"
    },
    "-K5lmtlJqtYfWlhdyGm6" : {
      "category" : "Sales",
      "comment" : "This is a comment on the task",
      "due" : "Fri Dec 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
      "notes" : "Note on the task",
      "profile_pic" : "url-to-picture",
      "read" : false,
      "task" : "Sales goals",
      "user" : "Jim"
    },
    "-K5mHm3a6DPYqjGx_eaN" : {
      "category" : "Sales",
      "comment" : "This is a comment",
      "due" : "Fri Dec 5 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)",
      "notes" : "Note on the task",
      "profile_pic" : "url-to-picture",
      "read" : true,
      "task" : "Title of task",
      "user" : "John"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this, is that I get the user for every entry. So a name will show up more than once, instead of showing each unique name. Is there a way to create another table in Firebase for just the users?

Comment: I think you need to group the data by the user so you can show only distinct values in your select. You can group the data directly in your firebird select or you can use a client-side js library called underscorejs.

Comment: Can you show your data structure, but as a JSON code snippet rather than an image?

Comment: I've updated my post with the JSON data structure.